# Why doesn't Firefox show the correct default select option?

Tags: firefox, select, caching

I'm making a web app to manage product SKUS. One part of that is to associate SKUs with product names. On each row of a table, I list a SKU and display a `<select>` box with product names. The product that's currently associated with that SKU in the database is given an attribute like `selected="selected"`. This can be changed and updated via AJAX.

There are a **lot** of product `<option>`s - 103 to be exact - and this list is repeated in the `<select>` on each row.

From another input on the page, I am using jQuery AJAX requests to add new SKU/product associations, and to make it clear that they're added instantly, I insert them into the **top** of the table with a little highlight effect. As the number of SKUs increases past 10 or so, if I refresh the page (which loads everything back out of the database ordered by product name), Firefox starts to show some wrong options as selected by default. It is not consistent about which incorrect option it shows, but it seems to be mixing up the options that existed before the page reload.

If I inspect the `<select>` using Firebug, the `select="selected"` is on the correct `<option>` tag. Refreshing the page (or leaving and typing this page's URL back in to return) does not make it show up correctly, but **hard refreshing (Ctrl+F5) does**.

Both Chrome and IE7 display this correctly in the first place.

My theory is that this is a result of a faulty cache strategy by Firefox. Does that sound right? Is there any way I can say in my code "if this page is refreshed, make it a hard refresh - reload everything from scratch?"

### Update

To solve this problem, I changed strategies.

- Previously, I put a `<select>` with a long list of `<option>`s on each table row, with the current value set as default
- Now, I put the current value in a `<span>`. If the user clicks a "change" button, I replace the `<span>` with a `<select>`, and the "change" button becomes a "confirm" button. If they change options and click confirm, AJAX updates the database, the and the `<select>` goes back to being a `<span>`, this time with the new value.

This has two benefits:

- It fixes the bug described above
- It requires **far** fewer DOM elements on the page (all those redundant `<option>`s)

Comment: If you read all of this, **thank you**. I know it was wordy.

Comment: It's amazing that FireFox still has this ODD behavior (ALL other browsers do not do this silly thing) and it's even more amazing that FireFox developers consider this as a good feature https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46845 rather than just an IRRITATING BUG!!! (still there in FF version 11).

Comment: This behavior should not be enabled by default!! The user should be prompt to opt in or out ( would you like to preserve you forms selections or something ? ). Here is one use case, say you have a cart and the cart content is updated on another page, then the user refreshes the cart page. The user should see the new changes!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Firefox preserves your selected form elements when you refresh. It's intentional. Ctrl+F5 is a "hard" refresh, which disables this behavior.

--

Or Command+Shift+R if you are on a Mac

Comment: I know, this is the correct answer. But how can we handle it without telling the user to press [Ctrl]+[F5]? Is ozu's answer correct?

Comment: -1 explains the problem but not how to fix it by adding `autocomplete=off`

Comment: @JohnMagnolia autocomplete is not a w3c valid

Answer (score 128):

I had a similar problem, but after adding `autocomplete="off"` HTML attribute to every select tag it worked. [I was using Firefox 8]

Comment: autocomplete is not a w3c valid

Comment: Doing this creates a validation error `Attribute autocomplete not allowed on element select at this point.`

Comment: I had a  same problem on Firefox ver 44.0 (2016-Jan). 
And this solution still works.

Comment: **Why do people prefer this if it's not valid HTML?!?!?!**

Comment: @doABarrelRoll721 **Because it works !!!** Other answers doesn't provide any non-dirty-JS way to fix this issue. This works as expected and is the most proper way to solve this issue (the iframe solution is terrible). And except if you're a W3C hardcore fan, adding this attribute does nothing wrong in browsers that doesn't support it.

Comment: @doABarrelRoll721: prefer this than what? jQuery hack or playing around with iframes? Please provide us better solution.

Comment: It's perfectly valid HTML. It doesn't have a standardized meaning prescribed by a w3c spec, so browsers are in principle free to e.g. ignore the autocomplete attribute on a select field, but that doesn't make it invalid. If all major browsers take autocomplete="off" on a select element to mean "don't remember the last selected value after a refresh", then this is a good solution.

Answer (score 16):

An easy way to prevent Firefox from caching the last selected option is to remove all of the option elements on page unload.  For example (assuming jQuery):

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  $('select option').remove();
});
```

Comment: autocomplete="off" does not work in chrome, this worked a charm. Cheers man!

Comment: just tried, this doesn't always work for me in FF (47.0) - unfortunately I can't investigate it further.

Comment: this only works for setting the select back to default on page refresh, does not work for selects with `<option selected='selected" >`

Answer (score 12):

I had this same issue. I was trying to change the value of the select depending on which option had selected="selected", but Firefox wasn't working.  It would always default to the first option.

Chrome, Safari, etc worked when I did this:

```
$( 'option[value="myVal"]' ).attr( 'selected', 'selected' );
```

... but this wasn't working in FF.

So I tried:

```
$( 'option[value="myVal"]' ).prop( 'selected', 'selected' );
```

and it works.

jQuery v1.9.1

Answer (score 9):

Although this is old question, but below solution can help someone

In firefox, I've notice that the "selected" attribute will not work unless you place the **select** inside a **form**, where the **form has a name attribute**.

```
<form name="test_form" method="POST">
<select name="city">
<option value="1">Test</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">Test2</option>
</selecct>
```

Again remember :

1. form must have the "**name**" attribute and
2. "**select**" must be inside the form.

Comment: Well, You saved me! I didn't need to add name to form, just `autocomplete="off"` but crucial was to insert `select` inside `form`. I've lost whole day on this because I didn't have `form` for this select.

Comment: for me this one works only. For firefox when I set name for the form then it works as expected. Firefox version: 54.0a2

Comment: I have a form with a name attribute but my select is still cached inside the form after page refresh.

Comment: Yes! This was the answer for me. And I saw it here first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12650918/470749

Answer (score 8):

I make it worked by putting the autocomplete="off" on the hidden input.

Comment: This is simple and elegant and works. Should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug has a cache disable function for exactly this scenario.

The deeper long-term solution is to work out how set no-cache headers server side. What web server are you using?

Comment: Is that something you can specify in the HTML?

Comment: This is internal to a small company. The web server is Apache, as part of XAMPP. It's running on a Windows server.

Comment: Here is a detailed walk through of no-cache settings in Apache: http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/cache/

Answer (score 0):

Every time I ever had weird select option bugs in Firefox it was because I had multiple options marked as selected.  Are you quite sure that only one is marked as such?  Seems like you could get out of wack pretty easily if you are changing that with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: in order to stop Firefox from restoring the previously selected option after page reload you can place the entire `<form>` containing the `<select>` options inside an `<iframe>`.

When select boxes are in `<iframe>` and you reload the container page, Firefox finally behaves like ALL other browsers, by simply resetting select options.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BananaDeveloper (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8258154/2182349) - this is my solution to solve this problem on a single page in an application

I didn't want to customize the off-the-shelf/open source application code

```
<Files "page_that_does_not_work.php">
        SetOutputFilter INFLATE;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE
        Substitute 's/<select/<select autocomplete="off"/n'
        Substitute 's/<form/<form novalidate/n'
</Files>
```

Apache docs for `mod_substitute` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html

Thanks to: https://serverfault.com/questions/843905/apache-mod-substitute-works-in-curl-but-not-on-browser for the **SetOutputFilter**

Answer (score 0):

Replacing jQuery

```
.attr('selected', true)
```

with

```
.prop('selected', true)
```

for `<option>` tag fixes it for me. All other solutions didn't work

Answer (score -1):

I've figured out. If you put onunload or $(window).unload (jquery) on your HTML with no-cache header, Firefox reloads the page and initialize DOM even from back button.

Comment: could you expand your answer with a proper example