# HTML selected="selected" not working properly

Tags: html, select

Hi can somebody tell me what is the wrong in the below code?

Selected="selected" not working for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <select id="tstselect" name="tstselect" onchange="showselected(this.value);">
    <option value="0" >0</option>
    <option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Worked for me with no issues. value 3 was the pre-selected item on my page

Comment: Looks fine to me. Works fine in JSbin: http://jsbin.com/awodej you must have something else going on in the page.

Comment: works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/88Hfk/ and seriously, HTML4 transitional? move on to html5!

Comment: I've onchange event in my code like onchange="showselected(this.value);" is there any impact?

Comment: better type in everything. you are not helping yourself by hiding stuff.

Comment: seems fine to me.  perhaps you have some random javascript deselecting combo boxes or something of that nature.

Comment: its working in all browser. can we look into all your html/javascript so that we can see if there is anything affecting it..

Comment: When I copy the source and copy into blank html page, it is working fine. I dont know whats the working with my application. there is no hidden javascript also :(

Comment: got it now. In page load there is another dynamic script which is accessing html control. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Future visitors: Depending on how you trigger page reloading, Firefox 21.0 (maybe other browsers also) will honor the dropdown position you last selected via ui, even though the html has the selected="selected" attibute set on a different option tag. Ctrl-r, selected option tag is not shown as selected but your last gui selection is. Hit return on the page address field in the browser and the visible selection is reset to match the option with the selected attribute.  Chrome 27.0.1453.116 did not show this same behavior.

Comment: For others with this problem, if you use CSS, check your padding property, I fixed it by removing/adjusting it. (Chrome 83.0.4103.119)

Comment: Adding `autocomplete="off"` to the form tag fixes this for me.

Answer (score 77):

You probably have something on your page selecting the value.  You *might* be able to quickly verify that if the same value is still selected after changing the order of the options in the html...

You might want to refer to:
[Firefox ignores option selected="selected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831848/firefox-ignores-option-selected-selected)

Comment: Agreed. Browser autocomplete has tricked me a number of times before with HTML forms. +1 for disabling autocomplete as a solution. The attribute can be applied to <form> or <input> or <select> tags. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion This is not too localized of a question, IMHO.

Comment: Ha! Of course! I have jquery setting the values when opening a dialogue and it cleared them when it was NULL. Sheesh... Thank you!