# firefox doesn't display text value in form when selected="selected"

Tags: forms, jsp, firefox, selected

Firefox doesn't show form correctly (Chrome and IE show same form without any problem).

In Firefox in first line in form text value doesn't appear.

In Firefox Firebug shows:

```
<td>
  <select id="refSearchType" size="10" name="refSearchType">
  <option selected="true" label="Option1" value="Option1"></option>
  <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
  <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
</select>
```

In IE View Source shows:

```
<td>
<select id="refSearchType" name="refSearchType" size="10">         
     <option value="Option1" label="Option1" selected="selected" />
     <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
     <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

My jsp code:

```
<td>
   <form:select path="refSearchType" size = "10">         
     <option value="${first}" label="${first}" selected="selected"/>
     <form:options items="${searchList}" />       
    </form:select>
 </td>
```

I tried to switch value of selected= to "true" or "yes" , doesn't work

CTRL+F5 doesn't work too

Please advice

Thank you in advance

Comment: This could be to do with Firefox's autocomplete feature. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831848/firefox-ignores-option-selected-selected

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding ${first} in line of option value

```
 <td>
  <form:select path="refSearchType" size = "10">         
  <option value="${first}" label="${first}" selected="selected">${first}</selected>
  <form:options items="${searchList}" />       
  </form:select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Firefox. They don't seem to care, since this has been around since pre-HTML 2.0

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=option-label