# selected = selected in Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to set selected in `<option>` tag.

**What is wrong with my code?**

My Code is:

```
<select required  name="site-list"   class="form-control" style="margin: 9px 0px 0px 0px;">

<option value="">Select</option>  

<?php foreach($MLCSites as $site) { ?>

<option id="emp"  value="<?php echo $site->site_key;?>" <?php if($site->id == $site->site_key){ echo "selected";}   ?>><?php echo $site->site_name;?></option>
      <?php } ?>

 </select>
```

Genrated HTML:

```
<select required="" name="site-list" id="site-list" class="form-control" style="margin: 9px 0px 0px 0px;">        
<option value="">Select  Site</option>  
<option value="HT45-YT6T">bizRTC</option>
<option value="EB22-0309">RTCBiz</option>
</select>
```

What should be my comparison to set **selected = selected** ??

**Table:**

[image: Tables]

Comment: maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831848/firefox-ignores-option-selected-selected

Comment: i have added the HTML Output

Comment: From your PHPMyAdmin screenshot, when do you ever expect `$site->id` to be identical to `$site->site_key`?

Comment: @Boldewyn Which two values can i  compare here?

Comment: @Rajan um, no idea? What value do you want to be matched, when the `<option>` is selected? That one then. Something, that is not part of the same `$site` variable, that is the source of your `<option>`'s value, most probably.

Comment: I am trying another way out by comparing another table's site

Answer (score 3):

You should use `'selected=selected'` and to avoids error, remove `id="emp"`, because id is for one value

```
foreach ($MLCSites as $site) : ?>

    <option value="<?= $site->site_key; ?>"
        <?php if ($site->id == $site->site_key) :
            echo "selected=selected";
        endif; ?>>
        <?= $site->site_name; ?>
    </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: i copied your code and pasted it but didn't work can it be my comparison problem?

Comment: i have added the HTML Output

Comment: @Rajan, can you show the site->id, maybe they don't corresponds

Comment: i am adding my tables please check so can you get an idea where i am wrong

Comment: @Rajan, you are comparing the site->id wich is 1 or 2 and site->key, this is a differents things. I think you have to review your logic.

Comment: Can you please tell me then what should i be doing here? I mean which values should i consider

Comment: Actually, they are no option. You have to use another data. Like the user->site_key if exist.

Comment: Sorry but how ? i did'nt understood

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109406/discussion-between-mathieu-lescaudron-and-rajan).

Answer (score 0):

```
.
.
.

if($site->id == $site->site_key){ echo ' selected="selected"';}

.
.
.
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: @Bono, I just changed user code from `'selected'` to `'selected="selected"'`. It was only a syntax problem.Most of the time simplicity is better