# Textarea in html says form should display one thing, firefox displays another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

So I have something like test 1 for a textarea that displays as a default option. When I refresh, users are taken to this page. They can go to another page that has test 2. When they refresh, they should be taken to the original page and shown 'test3'. The html is correct. Firefox does not display that correctly. What gives?

See attached image. 'test3' is from the page when I pressed refersh. The HTML says the box should be displaying "test inbox 2" It's not.

See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP6k9.jpg

This problem only occurs in Firefox (tested in ie and chrome).

EDIT SOLUTION: [Firefox not refreshing select tag on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870567/firefox-not-refreshing-select-tag-on-page-refresh)

Exact same problem as mine.  Just took me a while to find the relevant search terms.

Comment: Please post your code here, not as image links.

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing the issue? It's hard for us to assist you in debugging your issue through screenshots.

Comment: @BrianRay sure give me a few minutes.  Actually, is there a way to simulate multiple pages?

Comment: The attribute in the html contains the `defaultValue` of the input. if the value on page load is different from the `defaultValue`, either the browser is interfering with it, or javascript is. No, there is no way to simulate multiple pages in jsfiddle. i doubt you'll be able to create a test case in jsfiddle. You could at least though show some of your code here.

Comment: @Smipims no clue. I'm nowhere near an expert in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870567/firefox-not-refreshing-select-tag-on-page-refresh)