# PHP Dropdown Option "Selected"

Tags: php, selecteditem

I am programming a webpage which uses a `select option` dropdown menu to change the language in a MySQL table.  There are currently only two language options.  I simply want the menu to reflect the current value from the MySQL table.

I retreive the value from MySQL and assign it to variable `$valuelanguage`.  Here is the php code which I am using, that is not working:

```
<select id="language" name="language">                      
<?php 
if($valuelanguage=="en")
{
echo '<option selected value="en">English</option>';
echo '<option value="de">Deutsch</option>';
} 
else
{
echo '<option value="en">English</option>';
echo '<option selected value="de">Deutsch</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

At the moment, if my `$valuelanguage` is *de* then the menu should change to "Deutsch" as the selected option, but instead it stays at "English".  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: as you code shoes, if the $valuelanguage is en then the menu should be English as selected... not Deutsch you are not doing anything wrong...

Comment: note that most browsers won't change the values when you simply refresh the page. you have to do a force-refresh (e.g. shift-F5) to do a full-blown complete refresh before a select's option will change.

Comment: Of course I want it to change when it is Deutsch.  My point was that it is not changing.  YOu are right that I must use a force refresh however that changes nothing.  Is there an error with my string comparison?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not your code. I tested it on the latest version of Firefox but the refresh  (`F5`) does not work when I change the value of `$valuelanguage` to `de`. However, when I press `CTRL+F5`, the change takes effect.

I think the  answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870567/firefox-not-refreshing-select-tag-on-page-refresh), with the links it provides, is helpful too.

Comment: I have used every browser there is and there is no change.  Not even a frorced refresh is working.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed this function from an if then else to a case switch instead, which functions perfect regardless of refresh.  Here is the code:

```
<?php
$valuelanguage = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM configuration WHERE label='language'");
$lang = mysql_result($valuelanguage, 0);
{
switch ($lang) {
case "en":
echo '<option selected value="en">English</option>';
echo '<option value="de">Deutsch</option>';
break;
case "de":
echo '<option value="en">English</option>';
echo '<option selected value="de">Deutsch</option>';
break;
}
}
                                ?>
```

I have no idea why the If/then would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use some thing like this and tell me if it works

```
<select id="language" name="language"> 
<option value="en" <?php if($valuelanguage=="en"){?> selected<?php }?>>English</option>
<option value="de" <?php if($valuelanguage=="de"){?> selected<?php }?>>Deutsch</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <select id="language" name="language"> 
    <option value="en" <?php echo  $valuelanguage=="en"? "selected" :"";?> >English</option>
    <option value="de" <?php echo  $valuelanguage=="de"? "selected" :""; ?>>Deutsch</option> 
 </select>
```

try this.... if  $valuelanguage!=en or de  then select english. so you should be sure $valuelanguage==en or de