# Unable to post the form values without refreshing after changing option

Tags: php, html, validation, forms

I have a following form in my `HTML` code.

When I forget to fill in the surname,
the form will show me a "bubble message" `You have to fill in the surname`, then I
will fill in the surname, press the submit button and the values are submitted.

When I forget to change the default option from `<select>` the form will show
me a "bubble message" `You have to choose something`, then I will choose another option,
press the submit button, but the values are not submitted. I always have to refresh
the page. Do you know where is the problem and how to achieve it without refreshing?

```
<form action="add" method="post">
  ...
  <select id="choice" name="choice" 
     required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You have to choose something')" 
     oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
     <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
     <option value="first">first</option>
     <option value="second">second</option>
   </select>
   ...
   <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value=""
      required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You have to fill in the surname')" 
      oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
    ...
 </form>
```

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer below there is no problem with submitting the values, that means you need to give the complete code example.

Comment: may [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658784/php-dropdown-option-selected/26659241#26659241) help you ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the form data submitting as you will see from this jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/vbnh1a4y/

[image: post example]

```html
<form action="/echo/html" method="post">
  <select id="choice" name="choice">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="first">first</option>
    <option value="second">second</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="" />
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```