# Restore dropdown selected option on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form like this,

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<select name="alphabets" id="alphabets">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D" selected="selected">D</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I pull the page the first time, option D is selected. If I select option A from the dropdown, and then do a page refresh, I want the dropdown option to go back to D. On page refresh, I want everything to go back to it's initial state. But the dropdown displays option A, or whatever was previously selected.

Any idea how can I make the page display option D on page refresh?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you refreshing in Firefox? It is the only browser I've ever worked in that kept form data on page refresh. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479233/why-doesnt-firefox-show-the-correct-default-select-option

Comment: Have you tried the following in a document ready handler (or in a script block that appears after your select): `$("#alphabets").val("D")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the following in a script tag on your page.

```
 $(function(){
      $('#alphabets option[value="D"]').attr('selected', true);
 });
```

Comment: Placing this in $(window).on('load', function()  {}); helped me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 'feature' with Firefox remembering selection on select lists.

Add `autocomplete="off"` to the `<select>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#alphabets").val(localStorage.alphabets);
});

$("#alphabets").change(function() {
    localStorage.alphabets = $(this).val();
});
```

I think this will work (only in browsers that support [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)) but I haven't tested it.