# Value not selected in select list with firefox (works with chrome, safari, opera)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This code should select an option in a select list:

```
$('#ref_nationalite-pharmacien option[value='+t[14]+']').attr("selected", "selected");
```

It works fine with Google Chrome and Opera.

With Firefox (all version, I'm using Firefox 34), the option is not selected.

I tried to replace attr by pop, without result.

This is a short part of my code:

```
function actualiser_remplir_champ(reponse)
```

{
    var t = reponse.split("#");

Retour is (I changed private informations):

```
283##SMITH#Bill#1964-09-28#1987-01-01#Google Street 19#Mons##523601#1##sspf  formation specifique et generale##21#
```

The last number 21 is the value to select in my select list, it doesn't work with Firefox but works fine with other web browser.

Comment: try `$('#ref_nationalite-pharmacien option[value='+t[14]+']').prop('selected', true);`

Comment: Thank you, change nothing unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

This is a known FireFox problem and the solution is found in this SO-thread (which got it from another SO-thread): https://stackoverflow.com/a/10096033/844932

> Add autocomplete="off" HTML attribute to every select tag. (source:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/8258154/260080)
>
> This fixes the ODD behavior in FireFox.

Comment: Thank you, I have <select name=\"liste\" autocomplete=\"off\" id=\"ref_nationalite-pharmacien\"></select> unfortunately, it doesn't work.  What do you think ?