# Select box is getting selected in html(Firebug view) but not selected in the page

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, firefox

I have given the category list in select box. when I select some category it is getting selected, but once I refresh the page the select box is not displaying the selected category. 
If I check in Firebug view, it is displaying like it got selected. 
I don't know why it is not displaying the selected category shakthi when I refresh the page.
in chrome browser it's working..

My HTML Code:

```
<div class="range_select">
 <select id="range" name="ranges">
  <option value="">Select Ranges</option>
  <option value="2">AB</option>
  <option value="18"> Power Gen</option>
  <option value="6">ATZ</option>
  <option value="3">Power</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="1">Shakthi</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

My Codeigniter view page code for selectbox:

```
$ranges_select = array('' => "Select Ranges");
foreach($ranges as $range)
{
    $name=$range['name'];
    $ranges_select[$range['id']] =$name;
} 
echo form_dropdown('ranges',$ranges_select,$product_det[0]['range_id'],'id="range"');
```

Can anybody help me to find out the issue.
Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Which one is shown selected after the refresh in firebug? And which one is actually shown in the browser as selected?

Comment: HTML part of your code doesn't help any more. Provide the PHP code, so let us find out what happened.

Comment: Your html is fine, check jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/csb5rx0y/

Comment: @kRiZ:when i refresh the page,default option(Select Ranges) is getting selected in page.but in fire bug view it is showing above code (Shakthi option getting selected) and it's working in chrome browser perfectly.

Comment: @usermesam0023:the given code is codeigniter view page..$ranges_select = array('' => "Select Ranges");
        foreach($ranges as $range)
        {
         //$name=limiter($range['name']);
         $name=$range['name'];
         $ranges_select[$range['id']] =$name;
        } 
        echo form_dropdown('ranges',$ranges_select,$product_det[0]['range_id'],'id="range"');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the default behaviour in Firefox is to preserve the selected option as stated in the answers in these answers:

- [Why doesn't Firefox show the correct default select option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479233/why-doesnt-firefox-show-the-correct-default-select-option)
- [Firefox ignores option selected=“selected”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831848/firefox-ignores-option-selected-selected)

You can use a hard refresh to get what you want for you. (ctrl+F5)

Or as a permanent solution:

- use javascript to set the default on `window.onload`
- or set `autocomplete="off"` for the select tag

Comment: if i press ctrl+f5 na it's working...but client asking when i press f5 it's not working

Comment: Glad I could help... 
Which option did you use?

Comment: i have used second option..i already tried first option before posting this question..but that was not working.. I think, It might be difficult to identify for a beginners and I have tried many ways to clear this issue.. Then only I have posted this question but still, few people unlike my question. anyway, Thanks for helping me @kRiZ.

Comment: They may have voted down on the question because it did not show any code or any other way of telling what you had tried or were doing. But atleast you have got it working now... Good job :) All the best