# multiselect is not working in firefox but works fine in crome

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#ddlbrshop').multiselect({ nonSelectedText: 'Click to Select Shop !', });
```

I have a multiple select dropdown which works fine in crome but shows error in fire fox.
**Error:**
TypeError: $(...).multiselect is not a function

Please help me ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479233/why-doesnt-firefox-show-the-correct-default-select-option
follow the link

Comment: My data is binding in the dropdown but the chekbox is not visible and the data is binding in a list format rather than dropdown

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a jquery library and bootstrap library before your plugin:
i saw another post with the same issue. You should always place your css before any script.

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="../YKIOSK/static/components/multiselect/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script> This is my script